# AVSpeechSynthesizer doesn't work on iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

My AVSpeechSynthesizer code is not working on device (iOS 10), but it worked on iOS 9.x and it is working now in simulator.

```
let str = self.audioOutput //just some string here, this string exists, and it's in english
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
    utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
let lang = "en-US"

utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: lang)
synth.speakUtterance(utterance)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes"
UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}
0x1741495e0 Copy assets attributes reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x1741495e0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Result" => <int64: 0x1744203a0>: 1}
```

Before that there were error messages like that:

```
Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I know there is some workarounds (user has to go to Settings->General and switch Speak Selection, for example) but I don't think it's a real solution here.

**Update:** I created a new project (XCode8/Swift3/no other pods/frameworks and so on). It works in simulator, but it gives me the same errors on my device.

**Update 2:** It works on device. I have similar error messages (Unable to copy asset attributes and so on), but it works for now. I don't know what it was.

Comment: in your code try to check if your `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: lang)` exist, if not.. try other language

Comment: i tried something like that:         

let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
        for voice in voices {
            print("\(voice.language)")
            print("\(voice.name)")
            print("\(voice.identifier)")
        }

is it enough? I have "en-US" in this list.

Comment: try this: `guard let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex) else { return }` instead `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: lang)`

Comment: no sound (device/simulator). 

device: [MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
2016-10-06 12:02:13.537430[736:157767] Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}

Comment: simulator: [SpeechManager] -[AXSpeechManager _initialize]:339 Synthesizer created: <TTSSpeechSynthesizer: 0x608000116a40>
2016-10-06 12:04:43.632880 MyApp[74183:4880945] [SpeechManager] -[AXSpeechManager _dispatchSpeechAction:]:657 AXSpeech Should queue:  -> 0
2016-10-06 12:04:43.633268 MyApp[74183:4880945] [SpeechManager] -[AXSpeechManager _dispatchSpeechAction:]:667 Telling synthesizer to stop because this job doesn't want to queue and so on

Comment: If you believe you are seeing a bug, make sure to open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: make sure that the device is NOT in silent mode :D. Actually, that's happened with one of our customer.

Comment: @lithium Try my Answer once. Its working for me in IOS 10

Comment: @lithium I get the same "Unable to copy" error as you, but sound plays fine on device. Can you try on iOS 10.1 beta to see if it reproduces? Could be an issue with iOS 10.0.

Comment: @Leo Natan, unfortunately no, I don't have iOS 10.1 beta right now (and I don't have any free device to install it). But I also have sound now.

Comment: What changed since?

Comment: Actually, nothing. I created some function to play mp3 files (just in case), and added/removed some cocoapods (appsflyer). I don't believe these actions were somehow linked to this no-sound issue.

Comment: I don't think so. Could be that the voice was not yet downloaded. iOS downloads voices on demand in the background.

Comment: lithium, any updates on the bug report? Based on your last comment, it seems like it has already worked for you?

@LeoNatan were you able to make it work? 

I'm still having the same error. No cocoapods or any add-ons on my file, just the starter file. Thx

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 30):

Turn off your silent mode (the physical switch).
It works in my case.

Comment: The confusing part is that the physical button doesn't mute everything.  [aAVAudioPlayer play] produces sound... that's why it's not easy to spot this one... tx

Comment: You honestly wonder if you're going insane, and then it's something stupid like this. Thanks random internet stranger!

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this same issue on an iPad Mini 4.  This version doesnt have a physical switch.  But if you open control center (swipe up), there is a Silent button.  Turn this off and the issue fixes itself.

[image]

Comment: Issues don't fix themselves.

Answer (score 3):

In my project, although I was having trouble getting synthesis to produce the first utterance after initialization, I was able to work around that by rearranging code.  But I still have dozens of lines of garbage being spewed to the console when AVSpeechSynthesizer is initialized, and when its first utterance is produced.  Here is a little sample:

```
2016-12-27 06:45:08.579510 SpeechBug1226[2155:859123] [MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
2016-12-27 06:45:08.580248 SpeechBug1226[2155:859123] Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes" UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}
2016-12-27 06:45:08.585959 SpeechBug1226[2155:859123] 0x174157fa0 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x174157fa0> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Assets" => <data: 0x17426c700>: { length = 1237 bytes, contents = 0x62706c6973743030d4010203040506636458247665727369... }
"Result" => <int64: 0x174220180>: 0
```

I reproduced this in a [small demo project](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/SpeechBug1226) and was unable to find a workaround.  Sadly, I'm afraid that the correct answer to this question is to [***file a bug***](https://bugreport.apple.com), which [I just did](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4936466715115520) :(

Comment: Thank you. This proves that I am not going crazy. Couldn't find anything about this so I thought it was my code. Also made a demo project to reproduce it, so thought it was because of my specific device or something. Does it freeze for a moment (main thread blocking) when initializing for you too?

Comment: @Thermometer, I hadn't noticed that because, of course, I only create one AVSpeechSynthesizer in my app and re-use it.  I just added some code to measure and found that `AVSpeechSynthesizer()` blocks for 1.2 seconds in iPhone 5 simulator and 1.6 seconds in my actual iPad Mini.  Indeed, that seems pretty bad.  Is that what you mean by *a moment*?

Comment: Yeah exactly! Nice that you measured it, 1.2 seconds is comparable to the freezing I'm experiencing. I discovered it when opening a modal viewcontroller took ~1,5 seconds. Turned out it was just initializing `AVSpeechSynthesizer` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Very good, @Thermometer.  I just added the performance-logging code to my demo project, and "Additional Information" to my Apple Bug Report complaining about the poor performance.  I hope it gets their attention!

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario, I could solve it by enabling **Internet Connection** in iPhone.

> A speech recognizer recognizes only one language. When you use the
>   default initializer, you get a speech recognizer for the device's
>   current locale, if a recognizer is supported for that locale. Note
>   that a supported speech recognizer is not the same as an available
>   speech recognizer; for example, the recognizers for some locales may
>   require an Internet connection. You can use the  supportedLocales() 
>   method to get a list of supported locales and the  isAvailable
>   property to find out if the recognizer for a specific locale is
>   available.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer)

Answer (score 1):

I have try your code with just one change and its working. Try this once

```
 synth.speak(utterance)
```

My whole code is like

```
**`import  AVFoundation`**


        let str = "once" //just some string here, this string exists, and it's in english
        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
        utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
        let lang = "en-US"

        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: lang)
        synth.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: That change is related to Swift 3 (vs Swift 2.3 in the author's code). How does it provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: The language does not change how frameworks behave. Swift 2.3 or Swift 3.0, they both call internal frameworks written in Objective C. This issue has nothing to do with the language used.

Comment: You are typing nonsense. You can develop in Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8, and you can run apps written in Xcode 7 on iOS 10.

Comment: The issue here is that it does not reproduce. You can write it in Xcode 7 or 8, Objective C, Swift 2.3 Swift 3.0 or Swift 1.1; it works. There is a specific issue for the author that you are not seeing on your device.

Comment: @LeoNatan Sorry for disturbance. I should have learn new things from you. Thank you.

Comment: @LeoNatan Just try this code in ios 10. You can see output without errors he mentioned. Again Sorry

Comment: I have the same code and the errors appear, but I also hear sound.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem for me got solved by changing the language to "es" (my device is in Spanish), then it worked.
But I wanted the voice in English and it didn't speak with an English accent.
It turns out that in my device I had in preferences/accessibility/voiceOver/rotor languages the voice Niky selected but not downloaded (probably deleted automatically after a long time not using it). I selected Alex, the default one, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer() //initialize synthesizer outside the function.

func speak(text: String) {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

    synth.speak(utterance)
}
```