# Unable to copy asset attributes console error - AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

My console is getting spammed with these errors:

> [MobileAssetError:1] Unable to copy asset attributes
>
> Could not get attribute 'LocalURL': Error Domain=MobileAssetError Code=1 "Unable to copy asset attributes"
>   UserInfo={NSDescription=Unable to copy asset attributes}
>
> Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY   { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
>     "Assets" => : { length = 1237 bytes, contents =
>   0x62706c6973743030d4010203040506636458247665727369... }   "Result" =>
>   : 0 }
>
> Copy assets attributes reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY   { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
>     "Result" => : 1 }

It is very annoying when it starts spamming a console. I've read that something like disabling OS_ACTIVITY_MODE can suppress these logs, but I would like to find a source of it and handle it as it should...

This is happening because I use AVSpeechSynthesizer, like this:

```
  self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
  self.synthesizer setDelegate:self];
  self.speedCameraAhead = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Caution: Blah blah blah!",nil)];
  [self.speedCameraAhead setRate:0.5f];
```

Comment: is your phone in silent mode?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Not currently, the *Mute* switch on the side of the phone is in the *Ring* position.

Comment: Probably a bug: [http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4936466715115520](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4936466715115520)

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Seems so...

Comment: Try by going to Settings -> General -> Speech, and enable "Speak Selection"

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Nah, I am getting same errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879275/avspeechsynthesizer-doesnt-work-on-ios10/45622053#45622053